# Draw an image on the last page using Zend PDF?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

I know there is the drawImage function to draw an image. What i want is to only print my image to the last page of the PDF, on the bottom. How can I do that? This is the function:

```
page->drawImage($image, $imageTopLeft, $imageTop, $imageBottomRight, $imageBottom);
```

Adding coordinates here will draw it on every page on the given location, wont it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you create your PDF and Pages like this:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

$page1 = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
// set content to this page
$pdf->pages[] = $page1;

$page2 = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
// set content to this page
$pdf->pages[] = $page2;

// and so on ...
```

You can than do this:

```
//Get your last page with $pdf->pages[count($pdf->pages[])-1]

$pdf->pages[count($pdf->pages[])-1]->drawImage($image, $imageTopLeft, $imageTop, $imageBottomRight, $imageBottom);
```

---

If you want to find text width to adjust other elements you can use this function:

```
    /**
     * Calculate width of given text
     * 
     * @param String $text 
     * @param Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font
     * @param int $font_size
     * @return int 
     */
    public function getTextWidth($text, Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font, $font_size) {
        $drawing_text = iconv('', 'UTF-16BE', $text);
        $characters = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($drawing_text); $i++) {
            $characters[] = (ord($drawing_text[$i++]) << 8) | ord($drawing_text[$i]);
        }
        $glyphs = $font->glyphNumbersForCharacters($characters);
        $widths = $font->widthsForGlyphs($glyphs);
        $text_width = (array_sum($widths) / $font->getUnitsPerEm()) * $font_size;
        return $text_width;
    }
```

and than you jus call:

```
$this->getTextWidth('some dinamyc text ', $font, $font_size);
```

Comment: Looks good, is there a way to draw it without any of the x/y values? I have to draw it below another element on the PDF. The element is not at the same position all the time.

Comment: No, as I know. Than you have to set x/y dynamic with regard to another element x/y values.

Comment: How would I do that? The other element is text that wont change.

Comment: This returns me 67 ... what do I do with that now? Use it to draw the image? If yes, how? :)

THANKS!

Comment: then your x position of logo will be:
 x-position-of-text + 67 + right-padding.....